# What is the origin security for in a canvas?

Tags: security, html, canvas

I just read that if you load an image served from a different origin in a canvas you can see it but if you try, for instance, to access the imageData of that image, it is raising a SECURITY_EXCEPTION.

I get that, I just having hard times finding the reason for that. Do you guys have some example on why there is such a restriction like this one?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have uploaded some personal photos to a private photo storage service - now imagine that private photo storage service has adverts that use the canvas element.  If there's no origin restriction and I want to steal all your private photos, all I need to do is buy advertising space on the site, then use `drawImage()` to grab your photo then send the results of `toDataURL()` back in an AJAX request.

Comment: But you can still steal a picture and use it on your site using the <img> tag right? so I don't really see the difference :( I'm confused

Comment: @LaurentT How?  The `img` tag isn't scriptable?

Comment: I mean as long as you know the URL you should be able to use the image on your site right?

Comment: @LaurentT It would be a fairly crappy private photo storage service if you could just get the images without authentication.